# Elegant way to prevent unused assignment?

Tags: rust

##### Context

Sometimes I find strict typing warnings more distracting than useful while still putting some idea into code, and before having reviewed it for sanity.

I'm looking for a quick programmatic way to prevent "unused declaration" warning, in order to boost my workflow.

##### Example

I'll try to illustrate what I mean by an example.

```rust
// use rand::Rng;

fn breaking_out_of_nested_loops_using_labels() {
    let mut innermost_loop_reached: bool = false;

    'outermost_loop: loop {
        loop {
            // if rand::thread_rng().gen::<u8>() >= u8::MAX / 2 {
            //    break;
            // }

            loop {
                innermost_loop_reached = true;
                break 'outermost_loop;
            }
        }
    }

    println!(
        "Inner loop was {}reached",
        if innermost_loop_reached { "" } else { "not " }
    )
}
```

The code results with the following warning:

[image: compiler warning, indicating an unused assignment]

Obviously the compiler is correct.

##### Question

I'm curious if there is a quick way to "trick" or ignore unused assignment warnings during typing some initial code, when all you want to know is if the code still compiles.

How do experienced rust programmers go about this? or do you just learn to ignore the warnings until you're ready to process them?

##### Please note

The commented out code is what I used to prevent the warning from popping up, while still trying the code. Obviously importing a crate and using a random condition is a lot of work, so it's not ideal.

At that point I might as well put the `#[allow(unused_assignments)]`-allow-rule above my function. But that's what I'm trying to prevent having to do, because;

- I might forget to remove it.
- It would already interrupt my workflow if I have to copy warnings from the compiler output.

Comment: Well, I have doubts that a tiny little warning would make any serious distraction to my workflow. In my small draft code I usually use the defined variables right away. As long as you follow the guideline "define variables as close to where they're being used", the warning becomes less frequent. Maybe you write too big functions, meaning that they do several unrelated things, or maybe you use the bottom-up programming to the extremes, where you're better to use a top-down approach

Comment: Furthermore your output is properly colored, so you can easily distinguish compilation errors from warnings, so at least you can ignore warnings visually. If you do have too many warnings, maybe it's a red flag that you're shooting your own foot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control lint levels [via `rustc` flags](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/levels.html#via-compiler-flag) - so for example `-A unused_assignments` would banish the unused assignments warning.

You can configure Cargo so that it applys specific flags when it calls `rustc` [using a config.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) file, which you can place in the project, or your in `~/.cargo/config.toml`, or a number of other places - refer to the cargo documentation.

You place the desired rust flags inside the `[build]` section like this:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-A", "unused_assignments"]
```

Of course you still need to remember to remove this when you are finished the initial experimental coding phase, but at least it is not sprinkled throughout your code.

Unfortunately it is not possible yet to set the rustflags per profile - it might be great to be able to dampen down the warnings for `debug` but keep them all for `release`. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10271) open for this so maybe it will be possible in the future.

You can also control the rust arguments with the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable. I generally find this less useful for environments like IDEs though, which might make it hard to control the environment variables under which cargo is running.

Comment: I would be interested to follow this issue. Would you mind linking it if you can find it?

Comment: @Webber  I thought I had linked it already, but it turns out I had pasted it incorrectly! I've fixed that now.

Comment: Thank you. That feature request seems to be a great step towards creating even smoother workflows.

Comment: It seems that `[build]` table is no longer used  in `Cargo.toml` by `cargo`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try naming the variable `_innermost_loop_reached` instead.

Adding an underscore in the beginning of the name of a variable prevents the compiler from showing the `unused_assignments` warning.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to avoid the problem altogether by making using of the fact that `loop` can be an expression, and assign that expresion to `innermost_loop_reached`:

```
fn breaking_out_of_nested_loops_using_labels() {
    // Directly assign to `innermost_loop_reached`
    let innermost_loop_reached: bool = 'outermost_loop: loop {
        loop {
            if rand::thread_rng().gen::<u8>() >= u8::MAX / 2 {
                break;
            }

            loop {
                // break directly to the top-loop, "returning" `true`
                break 'outermost_loop true;
            }
        }
        // "return" `false`
        break false;
    };

    println!(
        "Inner loop was {}reached",
        if innermost_loop_reached { "" } else { "not " }
    )
}
```

This has the added benefit that all exits from the loop (via break) **must** be of type `bool` because `innermost_loop_reached` is a `bool`. That is, you avoid most cases where `innermost_loop_reached` should get a value in the loops but doesn't, wrongfully leaving the default `false` from your example in place.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Rust. The current version of `rustc` and `cargo` are both 1.74.1. I added the following to my package manifest `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[lints.rust]
unused_assignments = "allow"
#unused_variables   = "allow"
```

More information is available from

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-lints-section

Comment: As mentioned in my question, this is exactly what I'm trying to prevent. I did not wish to disable the linter altogether, as it's there for a reason.

Comment: Then i think the only way is to add the  `#[allow(unused_variables)]`  or `#[allow(unused_assignments)]` above the warning line, one by one.